# How do the weevils obtain and maintain their boilersuits?

Tags: torchwood

In the first two seasons of *Torchwood*, we learn the following about weevils:

- They live in the sewers.
- They partake in fights.
- They are rather unintelligent (e.g. they risk exposure often).
- They are not particularly organised, despite having some psychic link (e.g. they do not operate against the guys from the weevil fight club).

However, with a few exceptions, whenever we see weevils, they are dressed in comparatively clean, undamaged and uniform boilersuits. This does not make sense to me because they are certainly not able to produce them and even if they have found a big stash of boilersuits, they should quickly deplete it, as they cannot maintain them.

What am I missing? How do the weevils obtain and maintain their boilersuits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is discussed in the Torchwood Prose novel "[Another Life](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Another_Life_(novel))". In short, the weevils in their natural state **do wear clothes**:

> **It was a Weevil, dressed in the curious half-clothing that
>   characterised the creatures when they had only recently come through
>   the Rift.** The creature lay, shivering uncontrollably in the roadway,
>   its arms and legs spread clumsy and wide, jerking spasmodically
>   beneath a weak streetlight.

But they seem to prefer human-made clothes which they acquire through ***theft***. Note that shortly afterwards, the same weevil turns up wearing a set of overalls. Clearly he didn't have time to make them, nor the means to acquire them legally:

> Toshiko scurried aside as best she could, scuffling across the floor
>   on her backside. The sound distracted the Weevil for a second. Just
>   enough time for Ianto. He snatched the device he’d been carrying from
>   his jacket pocket, and plunged it into the gap at the top of the
>   Weevil’s overalls. It connected with the leathery flesh of her neck,
>   below the chin and her slavering fangs.

It seems reasonably likely that having got hold of clothing that they would make some crude efforts to keep it clean by periodically washing it.

Comment: Is there any explanation as to why they always steal the same clothes?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - They aren't very bright. Presumably, having found a relatively renewable source of clothing (such as a clothing store or clothing warehouse), they'd simply take what passes for Weevil fashion, then repeat as needed.

Comment: Their source of clothing is apparently Torchwood as the boilersuits have that word printed above the left breast.

Comment: @Blackwood - Very droll. I think the OP is referring to the ones that haven't escaped from Torchwood's holding cells.